# How to create equal breaks on the x-axis of the odd ratio by group using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to create an odds ratio plot by group using ggplot.
I followed the code from here with little changes based on my data >> https://datascienceplus.com/lattice-like-forest-plot-using-ggplot2-in-r/.
However, the plot does not looks nice on the x-axis values.
This is something related to the odd values using log-scale values.
I couldn't  find any related resources that can explain the fundamental of the odds ratio by group.
If anyone can suggest any good resources or share ideas on how to deal with the log scale values for odds ratio, it might be very helpful.

[image]

Below are my updated codes for the odd ratio plot:

```
boxLabels = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", "Group5", "Group6", "Group7", "Group8", "Group9")
df <- data.frame(yAxis = rep(boxLabels, 3), 
                 boxOdds = c(0.3851796, 0.7618974, 1.5911206, 1.5693252, 0.6270010, 0.9028512, 1.2447482, 0.5519381,
                             0.7975806, 0.3797523, 0.7694422, 1.5677458, 1.5745740, 0.6476573, 0.8856219, 1.2539064, 
                             0.5493547, 0.7999925, 0.4103117, 0.7495576, 1.5487911, 1.5820141, 0.6234662, 0.9275115,
                             1.2330548, 0.5473389, 0.7987249), 
                 boxCILow = c(0.1640893, 0.3755799, 0.8119323, 0.9861494, 0.3228037, 0.5118568, 0.7046579, 0.3411973, 
                              0.5149663, 0.1613715, 0.3799119, 0.8048746, 0.9828702, 0.3331744, 0.5071847,0.7107267,
                              0.3402916, 0.5171706, 0.1769493, 0.3700616, 0.8030618, 0.9863263, 0.3231824, 0.5201105,
                              0.6930103, 0.3399159, 0.5156547), 
                 boxCIHigh = c(0.9041620, 1.5455771, 3.1180736, 2.4973718, 1.2178619, 1.5925164, 2.1987947, 0.8928432, 
                               1.2352941, 0.8936634, 1.5583646, 3.0536769, 2.5224931, 1.2589801, 1.5464311,2.2122163,
                               0.8868589, 1.2374794, 0.9514349, 1.5182244, 2.9870102, 2.5374649, 1.2027576, 1.6540286,
                               2.1939415, 0.8813352, 1.2371872),
                 Group=rep(c("Missing rate 10%","Missing rate 15%","Missing rate 20%"),each =9)
)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = Group,y = boxOdds, ymin = boxCILow, ymax = boxCIHigh ))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(col=Group))+
  geom_hline(aes(fill=Group),yintercept =1, linetype=2)+
  xlab('Groups')+ ylab("Risk Ratio (95% Confidence Interval)")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=boxCILow, ymax=boxCIHigh,col=Group),width=0.5,cex=1)+
  facet_wrap(~yAxis,strip.position="left",nrow=9,scales = "free_y")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(hjust=0,vjust = 1,angle=180,face="bold"))+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=seq(0.0, 3.0,0.2),labels = seq(0.0, 3.0,0.2))+   #seq(0.0, 3.0, 0.5))+
  guides(col = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please clarify what "This is something related to the odd values" means. It sounds like you want it to look different -- how? Odds scales normally work on a log scale, because you'd want 2x to show the same perceptual difference as 1/2x.

Comment: "However, the plot does not looks nice on the x-axis values." Are you concerned with the varying spacing or the overlapped text? The spacing is intrinsic to having breaks with fixed 0.2 break width, and the overlapped text is due to including too many breaks, or too large font, or figure not wide enough.